# Pessoal estou fazendo um formulario em php ,porem ele não quer add os dados no banco de dados

Tags: php

Pessoal estou fazendo um formulario em php ,porem ele não quer add os dados no banco de dados, tem como ver o que esta errado?não esta gerando erro nenhum.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CRUD - Cadastrar</title>     
*********************************************************************************************
<?php
session_start();
include_once("conexao.php");

$nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$telefone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'telefone', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$cpf = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cpf', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$endereco=$_POST["endereco"];//atribuição do campo"endereco"vindo do formulário para variavel

$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);





$result_usuario = "INSERT INTO cadastro2(nome,telefone,cpf,endereço, email, created) VALUES ('$nome','$telefone','$endereco,'$cpf','$email', NOW())";
$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);

if(mysqli_insert_id($conn)){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p style='color:green;'>Usuário cadastrado com sucesso</p>";
    header("Location: index.php");
}else{
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p style='color:red;'>Usuário não foi cadastrado com sucesso</p>";
    header("Location: index.php");
}

*******************************************************************************************
<?php
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$dbname = "cadastro";

//Criar a conexao
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {

}
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Cadastrar Usuário</h1>
        <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
            echo $_SESSION['msg'];
            unset($_SESSION['msg']);
        }
        ?>
        <form method="POST" action="processa.php">
            <label>Nome: </label>
            <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite o nome completo"><br><br>

            <label>Telefone: </label>
            <input type="Telefone" name="Telefone" placeholder="Digite o seu telefone"><br><br>

            <label>CPF: </label>
            <input type="CPF" name="CPF" placeholder="Digite o seu CPF"><br><br>

            <label>Endereço: </label>
            <input type="Endereço" name="Endereço" placeholder="Digite o seu endereço"><br><br>

            <label>E-mail: </label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Digite o seu melhor e-mail"><br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ma cadê o arquivo `processa.php`? Sem ele não tem como saber o por que os dados não são salvos.

Comment: $result_usuario = "INSERT INTO cadastro2(nome,telefone,cpf,endereço, email, created) VALUES ('$nome','$telefone','$endereco,'$cpf','$email', NOW())";
$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);

if(mysqli_insert_id($conn)){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p style='color:green;'>Usuário cadastrado com sucesso</p>";
    header("Location: index.php");
}else{
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p style='color:red;'>Usuário não foi cadastrado com sucesso</p>";
    header("Location: index.php");
}

Comment: Edite e pergunta pressionando o botão [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/449952/edit) e coloque essas informações no corpo da questão.

Answer (score 0):

As chaves na superglobal `$_POST` vem do corpo da requisição, no seu caso, vem dos nomes dos inputs. Pelo que eu vi, o campo endereço está com nome "Endereço" no index.php e "endereco" no processa.php.

Este campo pode estar configurado como NOT NULL, causando erro ao inserir.

Agora para o PHP não estar mostrando nenhum erro, pode ser alguma configuração nele.

Comment: Usuário cadastrado com sucesso

"; header("Location: index.php"); }else{ $_SESSION['msg'] = "

Usuário não foi cadastrado com sucesso
"; header("Location: index.php"); }

Comment: Apareceu esse erro agora, eu troquei ç por c em endereço em index.php

Comment: Esse erro apareceu por estar na condição else, veja qual foi o erro retornado com: `mysqli_connect_error()`